# Why $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(Y)$ for a double cover $\pi:X\to Y$ with a nef, smooth and big branch locus?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be smooth algebraic surfaces and $\pi:X\to Y$ be a double cover.
Let $B\subseteq Y$ be the branch locus. We assume that $B$ is nef, big and smooth.

[1] says that $\pi_1(X)\cong\pi_1(Y)$ (See page 796). Why is it true?

[1]R.V.Gujar, B.P. Purnaprajna, On the Shafarevich conjecture for genus-2 fibrations, Math. Ann. (2009),343:791-800.

Answer (score 2):

In case $B$ is ample this is Corollary 2.7 of Nori's paper: "Zariski's conjecture and related problems". I am not sure whether this result is originally due to Nori, but in this paper you will surely find many helpful results in the direction you're asking for.